# Grails- how to verify the value of a params in gsp?

Tags: javascript, grails

I have to verify a value of a parameter which send from the controller.
How can I do it in the gsp using ?

Comment: Verfiy a value of parameter you mean to access value of params in gap right?

Comment: i have posted an answer please try and let me know

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assume your url is something

```
http://testdomain.com/show?id=12&type=test
```

You can access value of params in gsp using below code

```
${params.id} 
${params.type}
```

this will give you **12** & **test** in gsp page